# What is the appropriate tag for travel bans, in general?

Tags: discussion, tags

Despite all the tags we currently have, I'm having trouble tagging questions about travel bans in a way that doesn't [generate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50943/why-are-non-schengen-countries-excluded-from-the-covid-19-us-travel-ban#comment204224_50943) disputes/comments under the questions.

We currently have [immigration](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immigration) (as well as another on  the illegal variety) and also a tag [borders](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borders).

According to Wikipedia "immigration" usually refers to longer stays.

> Immigration is the international movement of people to a destination country of which they are not natives or where they do not possess citizenship in order to settle or reside there, especially as permanent residents or naturalized citizens, or to take up employment as a migrant worker or temporarily as a foreign worker.

The [borders](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borders) tag seems to be mostly about the shape of borders, territorial disputes etc., although admittedly I did tag one of my recent questions about border *controls* (on "rejections at the border" more precisely) with the mere borders tag.

We even have a [visa-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-policy) tag which might be appropriate if the travel bans are actually made by denying visas, but that doesn't seem to always be the case.

So, **what tags are most appropriate for travel bans *in general*?** I think we don't really have one, so I would suggest we either create a very specific one for [travel-ban](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-ban) or perhaps a more generic one [border-control](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/border-control) that would not be controversial when applied to travel bans of any kind. Wikipedia has a page for [border control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_control) starting with

> Border controls are measures taken by a country or a bloc of countries to monitor its borders in order to regulate the movement of people, animals and goods.

And among the headings in that article are "Quarantine", "Border security", "Immigration policy", i.e. how border controls interact with all these issues. So it seems we could use "border-controls" to tag "travel-bans" in general, although we could definitely have a specific tag for it, which might be a bit "loaded" semantically though. (Arguably you could conversely say that tagging travel bans with "border controls" is too euphemistic.) Or maybe we don't need anything new and "travel bans" should just be tagged with [borders](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borders)?

Your thoughts on this?

Comment: I do not have strong feelings on this, at least not yet, but I'd note that border-controls would include controls on goods as well as people.  If it were seen as useful to keep them separate, I would suggest immigration-controls and customs-controls.  (It is confusing that immigration controls apply to tourists and other temporary visitors, but that is how it is.)  Alternatively, immigration-policy (and, as needed, customs-policy) might be preferable.  Another option would be to broaden the scope of the immigration tag.

Comment: I don't think immigration is the right tag, but I don't have a better tag to offer. Travel-ban might be the right way to go, more specific tags aren't a problem as long as there isn't a lot of duplication/overlap. The text for the immigration tag would seem more appropriate to "migration-human-geography" meaning than an "immigration-policy-decisions" meaning.